# Kendo Combobox works with odata localhost but fails in production

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

So I have a really strange problem with the kendo web combobox with odata with serverFiltering: true

If I use it on a localhost server, it requests odata format and works great. Doesn't matter if it's pointing to an external server for the data (using CORS) or not. Either way it works great and gets data back the way it's supposed to etc.

However, as soon as I put it on a public domain, using the same browser it fails. And it fails in a most bizzare way:

It stops passing the $filter property. AND it stops calling the scheme.data function to parse the result properly (it successfully calls and gets ALL of the resultset because of no filter).

Further, it doesn't apply the results to the drop down, so it stays empty.

Absolutely no javascript errors are thrown. Putting breakpoints on the function for schema.data results in it never getting hit in IE or chrome. Same goes for change event and error events. Nothing.

Here's the data source:

```
dsContacts = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: User.serviceUrl + "/contact/list"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            if(dsLinks.selectedItem().LinkedToContactID() && dsLinks.selectedItem().LinkedToContact()) {
                data.results.push({
                    ID: dsLinks.selectedItem().LinkedToContactID(),
                    Name: dsLinks.selectedItem().LinkedToContact()
                });
            }
            return data.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        tradepointUtilities.ShowErrorAlert("Contact List Get", e);
    }
});
```

And the combo is defined as:

```
$("#cbo").kendoComboBox({
      dataTextField: "ID",
      dataValueField: "Name",
      suggest: true,
      datasource: dsContacts,
      filter: "contains",
      autoBind: false,
      delay: 300,
      minLength: 3
});
```

Again, works perfectly on localhost, fails in all browsers exactly the same way in production without any errors.

Ideas?

Comment: Further to this, the autocomplete control works perfectly.

Comment: What is the server response? Use your browser's network tab to see that.

Comment: Server response to the json only query is 200 OK, and it returns ALL records in proper format as expected. Which is what makes this so odd. The control, even though it received all of those records, doesn't fill the drop down at all. So it fails to use odata, AND fails to parse and display the data AND it works fine on localhost

Comment: I now see that the type of your data source is "webapi" which isn't supported. Did you try with "odata"?

Comment: yes, sorry. webapi is just me copying the odata one and modifying things for defaults. But I tried putting it back to "odata" and it does the same thing. Also tried "json" because the schema.Data function should be called and get the right thing anyhow, but it doesn't help either. Same results.

Comment: You need to use "odata" as type if you rely on the built-in odata support. Also what happens if you don't specify "schema" ?

Comment: Again, webapi is just a cloned version, and it does it with odata as well. Removing the schema makes no difference. Same results. Still requests without odata filter and still does nothing with the resultset and doesn't error or fire the change event either.  FYI, the schema code is there because the ability to allow a data property on the data source AND a transport so that you could pre-populate the result that the combo already has and fix it in existing data situations is broken in the recent builds (including yesterday's release) so I have to injected the existing values this way.

Comment: Sorry, can't help further without reproducing the problem. Out of more ideas.